# Code Instrumentation - code coverage in angular project without unit test

Tags: angular, code-coverage, instrumentation, istanbul

I have angular project and using Karma and Jasmine for Unit testing to generate the code coverage. I am now trying to my instrument code so that we can get the coverage report while manual testing how much code is covered.
I am not getting any references for integrating it in angular project.

I explored Instanbul provides the feature to code instrument with using nyc and babel but could not figured out how can i integrate it in existing Angular 14 project.
Please help me.

Comment: Use sonarqube for code coverage: https://medium.com/@learning.bikash/angular-code-coverage-with-sonarqube-d2283442080b

Comment: I am looking for options to generate code coverage without the unit test case. Getting code coverage with unit test and sonarqube is already in place. Thank you.

Comment: I was in a similar situation, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934710/1209166